# Iterate DataSnapshot using Dart

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart

```
void _newMessage(fb.QueryEvent event) {

    fb.DataSnapshot d = event.snapshot;

    // here want to process each of child of d

}
```

I think I should use d.forEach().  Are there examples of iterating over the children of a DataSnapshot using Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void addMessage( fb.DataSnapshot d){

    PCDChatMessage msg = new PCDChatMessage.fromMap(d.val());

    pcdChatMessages.add(msg); //todo don't duplicate messages

}

void _newMessage(fb.QueryEvent event) {

    fb.DataSnapshot d = event.snapshot;

    // process each child of d
    d.forEach((k) => addMessage(k));

}
```

That works for me - I had to get the Dart dynamic syntax correct.